# android preview not directing to the current object in the XML code

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

In the Android Studio preview I can't click on elements.

I want to find the current element in the **XML**  code by clicking on the object in the **preview**.

Comment: It happens to me also but not always, mainly after 1 hour or so of working with AS. It is disturbing though.

Comment: if we can fix it we would work faster as it helps finding the current element